# Arguments as my expected list in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a = []
def func(g):
  for i in g:
    a.append(int(i))
  print(a)

func('5435') 
func('76')
```

Question:

print results:

```
[5, 4, 3, 5]
[5, 4, 3, 5, 7, 6]
```

My expected result:

```
[7,6]
```

Comment: This seems to have been clear enough for someone to answer, but I don't think it is clear in general. There isn't a question here, or an explanation of why you expect the result you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable `a` is defined outside the function, So when you set or append to the variable in the first function it saves the first values because it's a global variable, So there's two solutions, First is to define it inside the function like this:-

```
def func(g):
    a = []
    for i in g:
        a.append(int(i))
    print(a)
```

and the second is clearing the global variable `a` after printing it inside the function like:-

```
a = []
def func(g):
    for i in g:
        a.append(int(i))
    print(a)
    a.clear()
```

Answer (score 2):

`a` is defined in the global scope. Why would you expect it to reinitialize in every call to `func`?

Either define `a` inside `func`:

```
def func(g):
    a = []
    for i in g:
        a.append(int(i))
    print(a)
```

Or a shorter equivalent:

```
def func(g):
    print(list(map(int, g)))
```